# Issue concatenating datafames inside loops scraping a web

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import time

# url = 'https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores?page='

url_list = [
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/discos-duros/500-gb/conexiones-m-2/disco-ssd/internos?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/discos-duros/1-tb/conexiones-m-2/disco-ssd/internos?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/placas-base/amd-b550/atx?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/placas-base/amd-x570/atx?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/memorias-ram/16-gb/kit-2x8gb?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/ventiladores-cpu?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/fuentes-alimentacion/850w/fuente-modular?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/fuentes-alimentacion/750w/fuente-modular?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/cajas-pc/atx/con-ventana/sin-ventana?page='
    ]

# store = 'PCComponentes'
# df_hold_list = [] # capture dataframe for each link
# extraction_date = datetime.datetime.now()

for url in url_list:

    for x in range(1,2):

        headers = ({'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES, es;q=0.5'})

        r = requests.get(url + str(x), headers = headers)
        print(r.status_code)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
        # print(soup)

        items = soup.find_all('div',class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4')
        # print(product)

        store = ['PCComponentes']
        df_list =[] 
        df_hold_list = [] 
        df_final =[] 
        extraction_date = datetime.datetime.now()

        for item in items:
            
            product_name = item.find('h3',class_ = 'c-product-card__title').text
            try:
                price = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-actual cy-product-price-normal').text[:-1]
            except AttributeError:
                price = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-actual c-product-card__prices-actual--discount cy-product-price-discount').text[:-1]
            try:
                old_price = item.find('div',class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-pvp cy-product-price-normal').text[:-1]
            except AttributeError:
                old_price = "Sin descuento"
            # try:
            #     availability = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-inmediata cy-product-availability-date').text.strip()
            # except AttributeError:
            #     availability = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-moderada cy-product-availability-date').text.strip()
            # except AttributeError:
            #     availability = "Sin Fecha"
            try:
                rating = item.find('span',class_ = 'c-star-rating__text cy-product-text').text
            except AttributeError:
                "Sin valoracion"
            try:
                reviews = item.find('span',class_ = 'c-star-rating__text cy-product-rating-result').text
            except AttributeError:
                "Sin reviews"
            try:
                brand = item.find('article')['data-brand'] 
            except AttributeError:
                "Sin Marca"
            try:
                category = item.find('article')['data-category']
            except AttributeError:
                "Sin Categoria"

            # if None in (product_name, price, availability, rating, reviews, brand, category):
                # continue
            
            print(product_name, price, old_price, rating, reviews, brand, category, store, extraction_date)
            
            df = pd.DataFrame (
            {
                'product_name' : product_name,
                'price' : price,
                #'availability' : availability,
                'rating' : rating,
                'reviews' : reviews,
                'brand' : brand,
                'category' : category,
                'store' : store,
                'date_extraction' : extraction_date,
            })
            df_list.append(df)
    time.sleep(3)

    df_hold_list.append(df)

    data_PCCOMP = pd.concat(df_hold_list, axis=0)

    store = 'PCComponentes'
    # site = ‘mysite’
    path = '/home/pi/Documents/WebScraping Files/pccomp/'
    mydate = extraction_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    mytime = extraction_date.strftime('%H%M%S')
    filename = path+store+'_'+mydate+'_'+mytime+".csv"

    data_PCCOMP.to_csv(filename)

    print(data_PCCOMP)
```

The code loop over a set of web pages which paginate over the page and extract the data in order to collect in dataframe.

Finally insert all the data collected in only one scv.

It runs fine but I am unable to append the dataframes in order to get only one csv with all the data in it.

I need help to achieve my goal, any help could be much appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, what I like to do when collecting data through webscraping is to build either :

- A list of dictionaries (which contains metadata) (**option 1**)
- Lists of metadata in a single dictionary with corresponding column names (data, title, price, etc.) (**option 2**)

(What I call "metadata" is all the pieces of information that describes a single item : in your case, that would be : the item price, the extraction date, the reviews on a specific item, and so on.)

When scraping is done, I build the DataFrame only as a final step.

As a final note, I didn't want to mess with your original script too much, but I think you should consider two things :

- Build a **function** to wrap your scraping steps (or maybe even a **class** so you can add a single function that handles all the similar things you're doing : collecting metadata on a product)
- You should probably replace "Sin Marc", "Sin Reviews" with `np.nan`, it will make your data processing and analysis easier

In the modification I did in your script, I choose **option 2**. I'm not sure about that, but I would guess that **option 2** is more efficient than **option 1**. However, I find it useful, sometimes, when you handle more complex data to build a dictionary first and then, happen the dictionary corresponding to a single item into a list of dictionaries (that would be **option 1**) : it can make it easier to track each item at a time.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import time

# url = 'https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores?page='

url_list = [
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/discos-duros/500-gb/conexiones-m-2/disco-ssd/internos?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/discos-duros/1-tb/conexiones-m-2/disco-ssd/internos?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/placas-base/amd-b550/atx?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/placas-base/amd-x570/atx?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/memorias-ram/16-gb/kit-2x8gb?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/ventiladores-cpu?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/fuentes-alimentacion/850w/fuente-modular?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/fuentes-alimentacion/750w/fuente-modular?page=',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/cajas-pc/atx/con-ventana/sin-ventana?page='
    ]

# store = 'PCComponentes'
# df_hold_list = [] # capture dataframe for each link
# extraction_date = datetime.datetime.now()

for url in url_list:

    for x in range(1,2):

        headers = ({'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES, es;q=0.5'})

        r = requests.get(url + str(x), headers = headers)
        print(r.status_code)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
        # print(soup)

        items = soup.find_all('div',class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4')
        # print(product)
        
        # metadata
        prices = []
        product_names = []
        old_prices = []
        ratings = []
        reviews = []
        brands = []
        categories = []
        stores = []
        extraction_dates = []

        for item in items:
            
            extraction_data = datetime.datetime.now()
            extraction_dates.append(extraction_data)
            
            store = 'PCComponentes'
            stores.append(store)
            
            product_name = item.find('h3',class_ = 'c-product-card__title').text
            product_names.append(product_name)
            
            try:
                price = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-actual cy-product-price-normal').text[:-1]
                prices.append(price)
            except AttributeError:
                price = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-actual c-product-card__prices-actual--discount cy-product-price-discount').text[:-1]
                prices.append(price)
            try:
                old_price = item.find('div',class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-pvp cy-product-price-normal').text[:-1]
                old_prices.append(price)
            except AttributeError:
                old_price = "Sin descuento"
                old_prices.append(price)
            # try:
            #     availability = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-inmediata cy-product-availability-date').text.strip()
            # except AttributeError:
            #     availability = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-moderada cy-product-availability-date').text.strip()
            # except AttributeError:
            #     availability = "Sin Fecha"
            try:
                rating = item.find('span',class_ = 'c-star-rating__text cy-product-text').text
                ratings.append(rating)
            except AttributeError:
                "Sin valoracion"
                ratings.append("Sin valoracion")
            try:
                review = item.find('span',class_ = 'c-star-rating__text cy-product-rating-result').text
                reviews.append(review)
            except AttributeError:
                "Sin reviews"
                reviews.append("Sin reviews")
            try:
                brand = item.find('article')['data-brand']
                brands.append(brand)
            except AttributeError:
                "Sin Marca"
                brands.append("Sin Marca")
            try:
                category = item.find('article')['data-category']
                categories.append(category)
            except AttributeError:
                "Sin Categoria"
                categories.append("Sin Categoria")

            # if None in (product_name, price, availability, rating, reviews, brand, category):
                # continue
                
        dict_metadata = {
            'product_name' : product_names,
            'price' : prices,
            #'availability' : availability,
            'rating' : ratings,
            'reviews' : reviews,
            'brand' : brands,
            'category' : categories,
            'store': stores,
            'extraction_date': extraction_dates
        }
                        

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_metadata)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My knowledge of pyhton is still small, I need to improve it. I think I miss something your code because when I ran the code adding pint(df) I only get the last rows not all the dataset.

Comment: Works fine for me :(

Maybe go through the code at your own pace : if you changed the name of the variables I created, be careful because I used plural names (categories, brands, reviews) for the lists and singular names (category, brand, review) for the single value of each line of the dataset.